# Use keypress to initiate action in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, stdin, keystroke

I am using node.js v4.5

I wrote the function below to send repeated messages with a delay.

```
function send_messages() {
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => send_msg() )
        .then(() => Delay(1000) )
        .then(() => send_msg() )
        .then(() => Delay(1000))
        .then(() => send_msg() )        
    ;
}

function Delay(duration) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), duration);
    });
}
```

Instead of delay, I would like to activate the sending of messages using a keypress. Something like the function below.

```
function send_messages_keystroke() {
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => send_msg() )
        .then(() => keyPress('ctrl-b') ) //Run subsequent line of code send_msg() if keystroke ctrl-b is pressed
        .then(() => send_msg() )
        .then(() => keyPress('ctrl-b') )
        .then(() => send_msg() )        
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put `process.stdin` in raw mode to access individual keystrokes.

Here's a standalone example:

```
function send_msg(msg) {
  console.log('Message:', msg);
}

// To map the `value` parameter to the required keystroke, see:
// http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm
function keyPress(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
    process.stdin.once('data', keystroke => {
      process.stdin.setRawMode(false);
      if (keystroke[0] === value) return resolve();
      return reject(Error('invalid keystroke'));
    });
  })
}

Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => send_msg('1'))
  .then(() => keyPress(2))
  .then(() => send_msg('2'))
  .then(() => keyPress(2))
  .then(() => send_msg('done'))
  .catch(e => console.error('Error', e))
```

It will reject any keystroke that isn't <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd>, but the code is easily modifiable if you don't want that behaviour (and just want to wait for the first <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd>, for instance).

The value passed to `keyPress` is the decimal ASCII value of the key: <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> is 1, <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd> is 2, <kbd>a</kbd> is 97, etc.

**EDIT**: as suggested by @mh-cbon in the comments, a better solution might be to use the [`keypress`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress) module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Upvoted. How do you get the value that 1 is Ctrl-A, 2 -> Ctrl-B and a -> 97?

Comment: @user91579631 see [this webpage](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm). The _"Dec"_ code is the number you pass to `keyPress`. For regular characters, see [this page](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_std.htm).

Comment: you should use tootallnate keypress module https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress

Comment: @mh-cbon I searched for something like that before posting my answer but wasn't able to find anything. It does look spot-on for this task!

Comment: I edited your answer, although, i don t quiet understand why the promise hangs if i type in the wrong key, makes this unusable. I definitely don t master promise.

Answer (score 1):

Give this one a try. As mentioned above, using keypress makes it really simple. The `key` object in the code here tells you if `ctrl` or `shift` are pressed, as well as the character pressed. Unfortunately though, `keypress` doesn't seem to handle numbers or special characters.

```
var keypress = require('keypress');

keypress(process.stdin);

process.stdin.on('keypress', function (ch, key) {
  console.log("here's the key object", key);

  shouldExit(key);
  if (key) {
    sendMessage(key);
  }
});

function shouldExit(key) {
  if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
    process.stdin.pause();
  }
}

function sendMessage(key) {
  switch(key.name) {
    case 'a';
        console.log('you typed a'); break;
    case 'b';
        console.log('you typed b'); break;
    default:
        console.log('bob is cool');
  }
}
```

And of course, in the `sendMessage()` function here, you could easily replace the log statements with something else more complex, make some async calls, call some other function, whatever. The `process.stdin.pause()` here causes the program to exit on `ctrl-c`, otherwise, the program would just keep running, blocking your interrupt signal, and you'd have to kill the process manually via command line.